# css div float and zindex -> div not accessible

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a web page (with div-elements) with a title (top), a menu on the left side, the main content next to it and a status area at the bottom of the page.
The menu opens to the right so I added a z-index on the main content. Now the main content (buttons, input fields) cannot be focussed by a mouse click - any forms in that area render useless (unless you use the tab key to navigate).
I noticed that it works (but breaks the page design) if I add the main content first and use `float: right;` then add the menu with `float: right;` as well.

I'm sure I'm not the first person stuck on this but haven't found a way of correctly dealing with this. Here's what the source looks like with the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div-g {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#div-t {
    width: 95%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #4422d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
#div-1 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #ee00b4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 1em;
}
#div-2 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #00eec2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 1em;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#div-3 {
    clear: both;
    width: 95%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div-g" style="text-align: left;">DIV-G (top)
    <div id="div-t">DIV-T</div>
    <div id="div-1">DIV-1</div>
    <div id="div-2">DIV-2</div>
    <div id="div-3">DIV-3</div>
DIV-G (bottom)
</div> <!-- div -g -->
</body>
</html>
```

If you save that as an html file you'll notice that the text "DIV-2" is not selectable anymore.
Can it work without using `float: right`?

Thanks,
john.

Comment: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qzv64/)

Comment: Just need to remove the z-index from #div-2 ( let it stack naturally ) http://jsbin.com/kesilovo/1/edit

Comment: The problem was that the menu (div-1) slides out to the right and then "underneath" div-2. That's why I used z-index in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used a negative `z-index`:

```css
#div-2 {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

That makes `#div-2`'s contents to be displayed below its background, so you can't interact with them.

If you want `#div-2` to appear below other elements, use a lower `z-index` than the other's one,  but a non-negative one.

Comment: Now that was easy! I added z-index: 2 to div-1 and z-index: 1 to div-2 and it seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never used a z-index of -1, you could try:

```
#div-1 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #ee00b4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 1em;
    z-index:10;
}
#div-2 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #00eec2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 1em;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that #div-2's `z-index` is -1. If you change the `z-index` to anything above #div-g's z-index, perhaps to 1, then it will work. The higher the `z-index` the "higher" it is on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/YFfDL/